# Python program to plot set of X,Y points overlaid on jpg map and remove some points with mouse click (based on features on the map)

Tags: python, mouseevent, scatter-plot

Can someone offer some brief comments on what will be needed to do the following in Python:

- display a set of X,Y scatter points (several thousand points) over a background map (jpg image)
- interactively use the mouse to delete certain X,Y points
- keep a record of deleted X,Y coordinates
- output the set of remaining X,Y points after deletion

Any comments welcome.

Thanks,